# xScale and yScale in Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a question regarding to the xScale and yScale when drawing a column chart with Canvas, here is the code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Bar Graph</title>
<style>#canvas{background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #ccc;
    border:5px solid #eee;
    margin-bottom:10px;}</style>    
<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas ;
var context ;
var Val_Max;
var Val_Min;
var sections;
var xScale;
var yScale;
var y;
    // values of each item on the graph
var itemName = [ "Red", "Blue", "Green"];
var itemValue = [ 12144,12179, 12144 ];

function init() {
    // intialize values for each variables
sections = 3;
Val_Max = 13000;
var stepSize = 1000;
var columnSize = 50;
var rowSize = 60;
var margin = 10;
var header = "Counts" 
    //

canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "#000000;"

yScale = (canvas.height - columnSize - margin)/ 13000 ;
xScale = (canvas.width - rowSize) / (sections+1);

context.strokeStyle="#000;"; // background black lines
context.beginPath();
    // column names 
context.font = "19 pt Arial;"
context.fillText(header, 0, columnSize-margin*2);
    // draw lines in the background
context.font = "16 pt Helvetica"
var count =  0;
for (scale=Val_Max;scale>=0;scale = scale - stepSize) {
    y = columnSize + (yScale * count * stepSize); 
    context.fillText(scale, margin, y);
    context.moveTo(rowSize,y)
    context.lineTo(canvas.width,y)
    count++;
}
context.stroke();

    // print names of each data entry
context.font = "20 pt Verdana";
context.textBaseline="bottom";

function computeHeight(value) {
y = canvas.height - value * yScale ;    
}

for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
    computeHeight(itemValue[i]);
    context.fillText(itemName[i], xScale * (i+1), y-margin) ;
}

    // shadow for graph's bar lines with color and offset

context.fillStyle="#9933FF;";
 context.shadowColor = 'rgba(128,128,128, 0.5)';

//shadow offset along X and Y direction 
context.shadowOffsetX = 9;
context.shadowOffsetY = 3;

// translate to bottom of graph  in order to match the data 
context.translate(0,canvas.height - margin);
context.scale(xScale, -1*yScale);

    // draw each graph bars 
for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
    context.fillRect(i+1, 0, 0.3, itemValue[i]);
}



}


</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="init()">
<div>
<h2>Pixel Value by colour</h2>

<canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="650">
</canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure what do the xScale and yScale mean in the column chart, I tried to play them to make some change to see what the graph look like, but still did not get the mean, please advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xScale & yScale variables are used in 2 ways.

**First purpose of xScale & yScale:**

They are used to fit your chart into the existing space available in the canvas.

For example if you change the canvas width to 450 you will see the chart automatically narrows the bars & spacing to fit into the lesser horizontal space. This is accomplished by the calculations used in xScale & yScale.

```
// The bars & spacing of the chart are narrower
// because of the xScale & yScale calculations
<canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="650">
```

**Second purpose of xScale & yScale:**

Charts often have their y=0 coordinate at the bottom of the chart.

In html canvas, however, the y=0 coordinate is at the top of the canvas

This line effectively flips canvas's normail y=0 from top to bottom:

```
context.scale(xScale, -1*yScale);
```

Illustrations:

**Here is your chart when the canvas is 400 x 650:**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=300></canvas>
```

[image]

**Here is your chart when the canvas is 500 x 300:**

No code changes have been made other than to resize the canvas element

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=300></canvas>
```

[image]